# Convert Android.Widget.Button to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, serialization

i am making an App where i have to save dynamically created Android.Widget.Button-Objects and its Attributes, like ID, when the App is closed and opened again.
These buttons are saved in an ArrayList.

My idea was to convert my Button-Objects into JSON and save them in the SharedPreference.

My Problem now is that i cant convert the Buttons into JSON, i am using following code for this, if found on stackoverflow:

(For Tryouts i am using a new Button-Object)

```
Button btn = new Button(this); 
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(btn);
```

Its working with String-Object or Integer-Object but not with Button-Object.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Tell me exactly what you want to do ?

Comment: You can't store / convert buttons directly as JsonObject.

Comment: I want to convert my Button-Objects into Json, so i can store them easier when the app gets closed

Comment: Or is there a better idea to store the Button or maybe the ArrayList with all the Buttons in something like TinyDB or anything? 
I am new to Android-Programming so dont know exactly what to use

Answer (score 1):

If you create your buttons dynamically it means you probably set a color, a text, ... to them.
So when you want to save them you only need to know how many buttons you had and what custom attributes you've set to each of them.

So you can do something like that:
You manage 2 lists, one with the buttons and one with their custom attributes.
To make it easier you can use a custom ButtonBuilder to manage the attributes.
Each time you want a new button, you create a new ButtonBuilder, you set the attributes, you generate the button and you store both the builder AND the button in 2 separated lists. Then you can store the list of builders in the SharedPrefs and regenerate the buttons from this list next time you open the app.

```
List<ButtonBuilder> mBuilders = new ArrayList<>();
List<Button> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * Display a new button
 */
public void addButton(/* List of parameters*/) {
    ButtonBuilder builder = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setBgColor(myColor)
            .setText(myText);

    Button button = builder.build(context);

    mBuilders.add(builder);
    mButtons.add(button);

    // ... Display the button
}

/**
 * Call this method when you need to regenerate the buttons
 */
public void regenerateButtonsOnStart() {
    // Get from shared preferences
    mBuilders = getBuildersFromSharedPrefs();

    Button btn;
    for (ButtonBuilder builder : mBuilders) {
        btn = builder.build(context);
        mButtons.add(btn);

        // ... Display the button
    }

}

/**
 * Custom button builder
 */

public class ButtonBuilder {
    private int mBgColor;
    private String mText;
    // ... whatever you want


    public ButtonBuilder() {
    }

    public ButtonBuilder setBgColor(int bgColor) {
        this.mBgColor = bgColor;
        return this;
    }

    public ButtonBuilder setText(String text) {
        this.mText = text;
        return this;
    }

    public Button build(Context context) {
        Button btn = new Button(context);
        btn.setText(mText);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(mBgColor);

        return btn;
    }
}
```